# Как правильно пользоваться Pandas для вычисления частоты вхождений в DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

Имею DataFrame:

```
ID  2020-01 2020-02 2020-03
1   'ex1'   'ex1'   'ex3'               
2   'ex1'   'ex1'   'ex3'
3   'ex2'   'ex2'   'ex3' 
4   'ex1'   'ex1'   'ex3'
5   'ex2'   'ex3'   'ex3'
```

Хочу получить следующий DataFrame:

```
      '2020-01' 2020-02' 2020-03'
'ex1'  3        3        0
'ex2'  2        1        0
'ex3'  0        1        3
```

Я, конечно, реализовал это циклами, но это же можно и нужно сделать в стиле Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [43]: (df
    ...:  .drop(columns="ID")
    ...:  .stack()
    ...:  .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    ...:  .reset_index(name="val")
    ...:  .groupby(["val", "index"])
    ...:  .size()
    ...:  .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
    ...:  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    ...:  .rename_axis(None))
Out[43]:
       2020-01  2020-02  2020-03
'ex1'        3        3        0
'ex2'        2        1        0
'ex3'        0        1        5
```

---

исходный DF:

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]:
   ID 2020-01 2020-02 2020-03
0   1   'ex1'   'ex1'   'ex3'
1   2   'ex1'   'ex1'   'ex3'
2   3   'ex2'   'ex2'   'ex3'
3   4   'ex1'   'ex1'   'ex3'
4   5   'ex2'   'ex3'   'ex3'
```

решение (пошагово):

```
In [53]: df.drop(columns="ID").stack()
Out[53]:
0  2020-01    'ex1'
   2020-02    'ex1'
   2020-03    'ex3'
1  2020-01    'ex1'
   2020-02    'ex1'
   2020-03    'ex3'
2  2020-01    'ex2'
   2020-02    'ex2'
   2020-03    'ex3'
3  2020-01    'ex1'
   2020-02    'ex1'
   2020-03    'ex3'
4  2020-01    'ex2'
   2020-02    'ex3'
   2020-03    'ex3'
dtype: object

In [54]: df.drop(columns="ID").stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
Out[54]:
2020-01    'ex1'
2020-02    'ex1'
2020-03    'ex3'
2020-01    'ex1'
2020-02    'ex1'
2020-03    'ex3'
2020-01    'ex2'
2020-02    'ex2'
2020-03    'ex3'
2020-01    'ex1'
2020-02    'ex1'
2020-03    'ex3'
2020-01    'ex2'
2020-02    'ex3'
2020-03    'ex3'
dtype: object

In [55]: df.drop(columns="ID").stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index(name="val").groupby(["val", "index"]).size()
Out[55]:
val    index
'ex1'  2020-01    3
       2020-02    3
'ex2'  2020-01    2
       2020-02    1
'ex3'  2020-02    1
       2020-03    5
dtype: int64

In [56]: df.drop(columns="ID").stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index(name="val").groupby(["val", "index"]).size().unstack(1, fill_value
    ...: =0)
Out[56]:
index  2020-01  2020-02  2020-03
val
'ex1'        3        3        0
'ex2'        2        1        0
'ex3'        0        1        5
```

Comment: Огонь! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
groups = df.groupby()
groups.ngroups
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = groups.size())
```

Попробуйте примерно так.